# I would like to combine 2 SQL Query in one Query - With Counting

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

Table 1 : `Questions`:

```
-Id
-Name
-AdditionalInformation
-Author
-QuestionCategory
-Date
-Time
```

Table 2 : `Comments`:

```
- Id
- QuestionId
```

I need to have as result all the tables from `Question` plus the count of Comments for each QuestionID.

Can someone help ?

What I've tried:

```
select * from Questions
union
SELECT Count(ID) FROM Comments Group By QuestionId
```

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: select * from Questions
 union
  
  SELECT Count(ID) FROM Comments Group By QuestionId

Comment: And also tried with joins

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I think both will work with that statment. it is my first question and he proposed it after i entered sql-server. Sorry for that one

Answer (score 2):

```
select q.*, c.commentCount
from questions q left join
     (select questionid, count(id) as commentCount
      from comments
      group by questionid
     ) c
     on c.questionid = q.id
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly enhanced version of above answer..
it will show you 0 instead of NULL if a question Does not have any comments.

```
select q.*, COALESCE(c.commentCount,0)
from questions q left join
     (select questionid, count(id) as commentCount
      from comments
      group by questionid
     ) c
     on c.questionid = q.id
```